# python black and white image detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, analytics

I am trying to identify if an image is black and white or a color image using Open CV in python language. i have created a black and white image using MS paint to check the same. even though the  image is black white it still  has RGB values other than 0 and 255. 
below is the code i have used and images i have used. the output i am getting is color image.
I checked the RGB values they have values other than 0 and 255, i am not able to debug why, can some one help me with this?

```
img = cv2.imread('C:/Comp_vision/image_data/black_and_white.jpg')

image_pixel =img.flatten()

bnw_cnt = sum(np.where((image_pixel == 0) | (image_pixel == 255), 1, 0))

if np.vectorize(bnw_cnt) == np.vectorize(image_pixel):
    print("Black and white image")
else:
    print ("Color image")
```

[image: the image i used]

Comment: disable antialiasing when you draw

Comment: I have used this particular image to test, there are other images downloaded too.

Comment: these images are not binary (only 2 colors black and white), but grayscale. You can compute the histogram for an image. If say 99% of the colors are near black (say <10) or near white ( say >245) than you can say that for your purposes the image is b/w

Comment: i checked the same if they fall in a particular range or so, they are very deversified.

Comment: so please post some image so we don't have to guess...

Comment: added the image " https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQd1S.png "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200380/discussion-between-bindu-madhavi-and-miki).

Comment: The number of colours in a black and white image is precisely two - black and white. The number of colours in an 8-bit greyscale image is up to 256 and they all have R=G=B. Is your question a) how to make a black and white image, b) how to make a greyscale image, c) how to detect a black and white image, c) how to detect a greyscale image or e) something else?

Answer (score 2):

Image will have black-white colors if and only if for given pixel (x,y) values on each channel will be equal.

For example:

```py
def check_gray(img):
    for x in range(img.shape[0])
        for y in range(img.shape[1])
            b, g, r == img[x,y]
            if not(b == g == r):
                return False

    return True
```

Comment: this works for gray images, what i am looking out is for black and white images.

Comment: Add condition elif b != 255 or b!= 0: return False